# msaccess report print preview goes into endless loop

Tags: ms-access, report, infinite-loop, print-preview

MsAccess - Office Professional 2019

My reports have suddenly started behaving in a strange way. All work perfectly in report view mode and, up to today, have been fine in print preview mode. Now print preview is going mad! There are 3 variations:

1. Some reports are ok.
2. Some reports go into an endless loop and the only way out is to kill access.
3. Some reports present with a very narrow single column report with no info (screen dump attached). If I click through the pages each page shows up the same and when I get to the last page it goes into an endless loop and I have to kill access. (Possibly this is the same as 2 above if the report is more than 1 page).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Print preview appears to default the assumed printer for formatting to last printer (driver) used by the pc. In my case I had not printed anything since producing some plant labels on a Brother p-touch a few days before - maximum width 125mm!!!. Hence the long and very narrow page.
I printed something to a 'proper' printer from another application and hey presto - everything worked again.